# Creating a URL prefix HTTP proxy gateway to a SOCKS proxy

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, tor, socks

I am trying to set up a system which will allow me to prefix a URL in order to route a request through a SOCKS proxy. For example, I would like a service running on `127.0.0.1:8888` such that if I were to request `http://127.0.0.1:8888/https://www.google.com/potato`, the service would make a request for `https://www.google.com/potato` through its configured SOCKS proxy, and then return the result to me.

My motivation for this is that my ISP has blocked all of my mirrors for Sci-Hub. I use Zotero and I have configured it to search for PDFs by looking at `https://sci-hub.tf/<doi>`. I can run a Tor service locally, but I don't want to redirect *all* of my Zotero traffic through Tor because I am a registered user and I don't want my traffic to the Zotero servers to go through Tor: I only want my Sci-Hub requests to go through Tor because that is the only thing I need to unblock.

I've been experimenting with nginx and Docker Compose to try and get this to work but I've hit a wall. I managed to set up an initial 'URL prefix proxy/gateway' service using the following minimal `nginx.conf`:

```
events {}

http {
  resolver 127.0.0.11;
  server {
    location / {
      proxy_pass $arg_uri/;
      proxy_redirect ~^(.*) http://localhost:8888/?uri=$1;
    }
  }
}
```

This allows me to visit `http://localhost:8888/?uri=http://google.com` and it will rewrite Google's 301 redirects to `https://www.google.com` to remain 'within' my proxy. I was planning to use [socks-nginx-module](https://github.com/dannote/socks-nginx-module) to set up a `socks_pass` directive as well, hoping that this would route my `proxy_pass` *through* a SOCKS proxy. Unfortunately it seems that these directives are competing with each other and I can't get it to work. :(

My objective here is to be able to chain the different proxies together by concatenating the URLs, which allows me to opt-in to proxying on a per-request basis. Thus, I would be able to request the Sci-Hub page for a given DOI through Tor by requesting `http://localhost:8888/?uri=https://sci-hub.tf/<doi>`.

I also came across [DeleGate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/), whose tutorial indicates it might be able to do this, but I wasn't able to get it to compile on Arch, and the latest binaries are old and don't link against my current SSL libraries. D:

So at this point I'm kind of stuck. I haven't been able to find any existing software to perform this 'URL prefix' style proxying I am describing, and I'm not sure how I can build a reverse proxy in nginx which will allow me to achieve this.

Does anyone know of any software I can cobble together with Tor in order to create this kind of system? Or can someone guide me in how I can configure nginx to perform dynamic reverse proxying via a SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working with a trivial Node.js script:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const SocksProxyAgent = require('socks-proxy-agent');

const httpsAgent = new SocksProxyAgent('socks5://localhost:9050');

const app = express();

app.all(/\/.*/, (req, res) => {
  const target = req.path.substring(1);
  const targetRes = axios.request({
    url: target,
    method: req.method,
    httpAgent: httpsAgent,
    httpsAgent,
  });
  targetRes.then(re => {
    res.status(re.status);
    res.set(re.headers);
    res.send(re.data);
  });
});

app.listen(8888);
```

Comment: After some more testing, this is not robust against many websites, especially against those with Cloudflare protection, but it is sufficient to get Sci-Hub working again :)